# Where does openstack_networking_port_v2 show up in OpenStack Horizons (web interface)?

Tags: openstack

I'm creating an instance with Terraform and I'm using the [Terraform resource `openstack_networking_port_v2`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/terraform-provider-openstack/openstack/latest/docs/resources/networking_port_v2). I can see this corresponds to [a `openstack.network.v2.port` OpenStack resource](https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/resources/network/v2/port.html).

I'm using this,

```
data "openstack_networking_network_v2" "network" {
        name = "public"
}

data "openstack_networking_subnet_v2" "subnet" {
        name = "hou-prod-external-ipv4"
}

resource "openstack_networking_port_v2" "myport" {
  name           = "port"
  network_id     = data.openstack_networking_network_v2.network.id
  admin_state_up = "true"
  fixed_ip {
      subnet_id  = data.openstack_networking_subnet_v2.subnet.id
  }
}
```

Creating this instance works in Terraform, but when I log into to Horizons I don't see this reflected in the UI anywhere. Does the `openstack_networking_port_v2` show up anywhere in Horizons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ports set up with `openstack_networking_port_v2` in Horizons you'll want to,

- On the Navigation bar on the left, click `Network` to open the drop down.
- Under the drop down click on `Networks`
- Click on the `openstack_networking_network_v2` in the case above `public`
- Click on the `openstack_networking_port_v2` in the case above `myport`
- You can now verify it's right by checking the ID against the ID recorded by your teraform state with something like this,

  ```
  terraform show -json |
    jq '.values.root_module.resources[] | select(.type=="openstack_networking_port_v2") | .values.id'
  ```